# php number_format, hide null from stored procedure

Tags: php, stored-procedures, number-formatting

I use sql server stored proc in my php project. In a table, there are some columns has numbers and some others are only empty (NULL in the sql stored proc). But when i use number_format, it appear 0. That's not what i want, i would like to have empty space. Is it possible? Here what i have until now :

```
<td style="text-align: right">
<?php echo number_format($row['Quantite']) . " ";
if (is_null($row['Quantite'])){ echo ' ';}?></td>
```

Thank you to help me!

Comment: I resolved it like that : <td style="text-align: right"><?php echo is_null($row['Montant']) ? ' ' : number_format($row['Montant'],2, ".", " ") . " $";?></td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

Edit the second param of number_format (2) for more decimals.

```
echo is_null($number) ? ' ' : number_format($number, 2, ",", " ") . "$ ";
```

Comment: it's just perfect!! thank you! but i will lose the space that i had between number and how about to add $ to the end?

Comment: it doesn't work with "." if i use "," it add $, but on the null columns too. More on it, the space 1 000 000 isn't there anymore, only 1000.00. Any ideas? Thank you again

Comment: Updated. For me now it prints 100 000$ if $number is equal to 100000

Comment: yes, it's currency, so need to use decimal number with space.

Comment: Wait... So if your number is 100000.99, then it should write 100 000,99$ ?

Comment: yes exactly and not show anything for NULL section.

Comment: Alright, updated. The number 2 in the code specifies the number of decimals. If you want to present a number like 999.999 change that to 3.
If you have further questions, please open a new question and mark this solved, because it's not the way you are asking for help in SO. :D